# display records for first day from selcted date range and end date from selected date range.Date range could be any date

Tags: sql, hana

I need to show open and close stock for a user input date range.

For open stock it should take the stock in first day from selected date range and close stock it should take stock in end date from selected date range.

Let say I have **data from 3rd Jan. to 30th Jan. (in database)** and **user has selected date range (1st Jan. to 31st Jan.)** so in open stock it should display **stock for 3rd Jan.** and in close stock it should display **stock for 30th Jan.**

How can I do this in SAP HANA Studio?

Comment: Post some sample data with your expected output from them.

Comment: Please refer to Stack Overflow "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: For stock model related questions it’s really important to provide an example of what entries in the table look like. It’s rather impractical to assume that it would always contain a full snapshot of stock for every day (somebody would do the stock taking daily). So some implementations nix snapshots and movement/delta entries which then need to be rolled up correctly to find the actual stock at any given point in time. Finding the next valid timestamps is only part of the problem.

Comment: To be able to answer this properly, show your table definition. If it's a view, show the definition of all involved tables and the view.

Answer (score 0):

making a guess on how your source data look. I made an attempt to solve your problem.

```
with data as (
--here are some example data
select to_date('2019-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd') d ,-1 stock from dual union all
select to_date('2020-01-03','yyyy-mm-dd') d ,1 stock from dual union all
select to_date('2020-01-04','yyyy-mm-dd') d ,2 stock from dual union all
select to_date('2020-01-30','yyyy-mm-dd') d ,3 stock from dual union all
select to_date('2020-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') d ,2 stock from dual 
)
,filt_data as (
select * from data
where d between to_date('2020-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2020-01-31','yyyy-mm-dd')
)
, min_date as(
select min(d) d from filt_data
)
, max_date as(
select max(d) d from filt_data
)
select (select d from filt_data where d = (select d from min_date)) open_stock_date
      ,(select stock from filt_data where d = (select d from min_date)) open_stock
      ,(select d from filt_data where d = (select d from max_date)) close_stock_date
      ,(select stock from filt_data where d = (select d from max_date)) close_stock
from  dual ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query might do what you are looking for :

```
SELECT 
 MAX(CASE WHEN S.dateStock = DT.minDate THEN S.dateStock END) AS openDate,
 MAX(CASE WHEN S.dateStock = DT.minDate THEN S.value END) AS openStock,
 MAX(CASE WHEN S.dateStock = DT.maxDate THEN S.dateStock END) AS closeDate,
 MAX(CASE WHEN S.dateStock = DT.maxDate THEN S.value END) AS closeStock
FROM
 stock S
JOIN(
 SELECT 
  min(dateStock) as minDate, 
  max(dateStock) as maxDate
 FROM stock 
 WHERE dateStock BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
) DT ON S.dateStock = DT.minDate OR S.dateStock = DT.maxDate
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ff45efc73032e16bd680869c681518d8)